# Interpretation of smaller-than-one odds-ratios in logistic regression with multi-category categorical independent variables

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, odds-ratio, binary-data

I've run a binary logistic regression analysis, and I’m unsure how to interpret some of the odds-ratios. I tested the predictive capacity of three independent categorical variables on a binary dependent variable, and in one of those categorical variables (one with five categories), all four categories test significant compared to the reference category, and all have odds ratios < 1. The largest of the four odds-ratios is 0.13. May I then conclude that all categories are at least (1-0.13=0.87=) 87% less likely than the reference category to achieve dependent outcome 1? Or doesn't that add up? Thanks in advance for the help!